# Repeated random number questions

Tags: android, random, textview

I have the following class which needs to display random questions to the user.

However my issue is that the class displays only one question rather than asking questions continuously .
How can I repeat user questions in order to keep their! score?
See image below - [image]

```
public class Chooser extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int randomOne = 0;
    int randomTwo = 0;
    int problems = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int userAnswer = 0;
    int correct = 0;
    int inCorrect = 0;
    int userInput, result;

    TextView question, response, answer, report;
    EditText userNumber;
    Button ans;
    private Random add;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chooser);

        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answers);
        report = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.report);
        userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        ans = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ans.setOnClickListener(this);
        add = new Random();
        randomOne = add.nextInt(20);
        randomTwo = add.nextInt(10);
        Display();

    }

    public void Display() {
        sum = randomOne + randomTwo;
        question.setText(randomOne + " +  " + randomTwo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        userInput = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());
        Log.e("getting user input", "" + userInput);

        if (userInput == sum) {

            response.append(" CORRECT! , You are the best \n");

            correct++;
        } else {

            response.append("INCORRECT, The correct answer was  :" + sum + "\n");

            inCorrect++;
        }

        problems++;


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your question but assuming you want a differnet "problem" displayed to the user each time he clicks the "submit" button you should call the "Display()" method after button click and also generate new random numbers by setting each time randomOne &randomTwo to nextInt(some_number)...hope this is helpful..